# How to access data in nested JSON in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swift2

I have a [json file](https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/maz0qqmvcx21/entries?access_token=ae8163cb8390af28cd3d7e28aba405bac8284f9fe4375a605782170aef2b0b48)

I need to get the latest `"id": "article"` `"createdAt": "2016-04-22T03:38:39.130Z"` date. How do I go about getting this data from the request in swift?

Note: Sorry im a swift newb.

Comment: should try SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let url = "https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/maz0qqmvcx21/entries?access_token=ae8163cb8390af28cd3d7e28aba405bac8284f9fe4375a605782170aef2b0b48";
var jsonData:NSData?

do{
    jsonData = try NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached)
    let jsonObject:AnyObject? = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
    if let itemArray = jsonObject?.objectForKey("items") as? NSArray{
        for item in itemArray{
            if let sysItem = item.objectForKey("sys"){
                //this is createdAt
                if let createdAt = sysItem.objectForKey("createdAt") as? String{
                    print("createdAt:\(createdAt)")
                }

                if let contentTypeItem = sysItem.objectForKey("contentType")!.objectForKey("sys"){
                    //this is id
                    if let id = contentTypeItem.objectForKey("id") as? String{
                        print("id:\(id)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}catch let err as NSError{
    print("err:\(err)")
}
```

This code dosen't use any libraries,but you can use SwiftyJSON,this is will be easy to parse json.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem :).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in simple way. I am assuming that you have parsed your json to dictionary

You have a key with items which is an array of dictionary and inside that dictionary you have createdAt and id(well it is deeper into the hierarchy but I will show you how to get it) keys. You can access it by simply doing this.

```
for dict in jsonDict["items"] as! Array<NSDictionary> {
    let sysDict = dict["sys"] as! NSDictionary
    print(sysDict["createdAt"]) //prints all createdAt in the array
    let contentDict = sysDict["contentType"]
    print((contentDict["sys"] as! NSDictionary)["id"]) // prints all ids
}
```

Hope this helps.